# Low accuracy for TF-IDF with SVM using TfidfVectorizer and Scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, feature-extraction, tf-idf, text-classification

I'm trying to classify documents as deceptive or truthful using TF-IDF and SVM. I know that this has been done before but I'm not quite sure I'm implementing it right. I have a corpus of texts and am building the TF-IDF such as

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, binary=0, use_idf=1, smooth_idf=0, sublinear_tf=1)
tf_idf_model = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
features = tf_idf_model.toarray()
```

And for the classification:

```
seed = random.random()
random.seed(seed)
random.shuffle(features)
random.seed(seed)
random.shuffle(labels)

features_folds = np.array_split(features, folds)
labels_folds = np.array_split(labels, folds)

for C_power in C_powers:
    scores = []
    start_time = time.time()
    svc = svm.SVC(C=2**C_power, kernel='linear')

    for k in range(folds):       
        features_train = list(features_folds)
        features_test = features_train.pop(k)
        features_train = np.concatenate(features_train)
        labels_train = list(labels_folds)
        labels_test = labels_train.pop(k)
        labels_train = np.concatenate(labels_train)
        scores.append(svc.fit(features_train, labels_train).score(features_test, labels_test))

    print(scores)
```

But I'm receiving an accuracy of ~50%. My corpus is 1600 texts.

Comment: You might want to post a confusion matrix or more metrics than just the accuracy.

Comment: me too......... that's unbelievebly low considering the fact when uses some clustering algorithm it quite correctly picks the groups keywords

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to reduce the TF-IDF matrix before feeding it into SVM because SVM is not quite good at handling large sparse matrix. I would suggest using TruncatedSVD to reduce the dimensionality of the TF-IDF matrix.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, binary=0, use_idf=1, smooth_idf=0, sublinear_tf=1)
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=20)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', vectorizer),
    ('svd', svd)])

features = pipeline.fit_transform(corpus)
```

Of course you need to tune the `n_components` to find the optimal number of components to keep.

Comment: I can't get it to work, got error `TypeError: unbound method fit_transform() must be called with Pipeline instance as first argument (got list instance instead)`

Comment: @Knokkelgeddon, did you call `fit_transform` as a method of `Pipeline`? Can you show me the line of your script where this error occurred?

Comment: it lowered the accuracy from 50% to 30% when i added the TruncatedSVD :)